# I can't launch a node

Tags: ros, roslauch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created this node and when i launch it, happened this

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [nmea_navsat_driver/nmea_serial_driver]: can't locate node [nmea_serial_driver] in package [nmea_navsat_driver]
```

My state variables are it:

```
jorge_j@Ulises:~/catkin_ws$ export | grep ROS
declare -x ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES="/home/jorge_j/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp"
declare -x ROS_DISTRO="indigo"
declare -x ROS_ETC_DIR="/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros"
declare -x ROS_MASTER_URI="http://localhost:11311"
declare -x ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/home/jorge_j/catkin_ws/src:/home/jorge_j/catkin_ws/install/share:/home/jorge_j/catkin_ws/install/stacks:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks"
declare -x ROS_ROOT="/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros"
declare -x ROS_TEST_RESULTS_DIR="/home/jorge_j/catkin_ws/build/test_results"
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209426/i-can%27t-launch-a-node/) by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2015-05-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-05-18**:
Where does `$ roscd nmea_navsat_driver` lead you to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all:
The problem was that i copied the files with a pen drive, and lost the permission for execution and occulted files.

Thanks and regards!

---

Originally posted by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) with karma: 183 on 2015-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the package and the source file exist, there can be a couple of reasons why it cannot locate a node.

1. If it is Python, make sure the
   node file is executable

   > ```
   > chmod +x nmea_navsat_driver
   > ```
2. If it is C++,
   make sure it is correctly defined in
   your CMakelists.txt and everything
   is compiled correctly:

   > ```
   > add_executable(nmea_navsat_driver src/foo.cpp)
   > ```
3. Make sure that your
   path is setup correctly, i.e. source
   the correct bash file (this seems
   correct for your setup)

---

Originally posted by [daenny](https://answers.ros.org/users/3203/daenny/) with karma: 376 on 2015-05-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2